# Python: pass sys.argv when loading python script with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, sys

I have a script that opens a file using subprocess.Popen so I can run it in the background. I would like to be able to run this script with ./[script] [params]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"./pyqt")
import gui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subprocess.Popen(["python", "./pyqt/gui.py"])
```

gui.py can take parameters when being ran from a terminal by using sys.argv. Below is how I am accessing these params in gui.py

```
def main(*args):
    print(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

How can I pass sys.argv into subprocess.Popen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just forward/concatenate the arguments in the `subprocess.Popen()` call:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    subprocess.Popen(["python", "./pyqt/gui.py"] + sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Hey that worked! I tried doing that before but I include the sys.argv inside the outer bracket.