# Is it possible to access the args given to it when running a bokeh server by a subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, bokeh, argv

I have a file `script.py` with code that opens a `bokeh` server like so:

```
def start_bokeh_server():
   subprocess.Popen(
       ["bokeh", "serve",
        "--show", "app.py",
        "--port", port,
        "--args", args])
```

In `app.py`, I would like to read in `args`.

In the documentation it says that it is possible to access the content of `args` inside the bokeh app with `sys.argv`.
However, with using `subprocess`, `sys.argv` returns only the args to `script.py`, namely only the path to it.

Is it possible to view the args of the subprocess bokeh call inside the app?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Here is the documentation to `bokeh serve`: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/command/subcommands/serve.html

Comment: It seems like for non-bokeh scripts it worked... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661246/python-pass-sys-argv-when-loading-python-script-with-subprocess-popen, interesting

Comment: Could you please provide the code of `app.py`, or at least enough of it to let us reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I used as `app.py` just to read input arguments -

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

Here is my script.py. I will pass the arguments to script.py from command line -

```
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["bokeh", "serve", "--show", "app.py", "--port", "5006", \
"--args", sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]])
```

I called the script using `python script.py t1 t2 t3`, I am getting follwoing output -

```
2020-08-17 11:30:07,248 Starting Bokeh server version 0.12.16 (running on Tornado 5.0.2)
2020-08-17 11:30:07,253 Bokeh app running at: http://localhost:5006/app
2020-08-17 11:30:07,253 Starting Bokeh server with process id: 78543
['app.py', 't1', 't2', 't3']
```

This clearly indicates, that I am able to read passed arguments inside app.py